# How to get previous 52 weeks from todays date

Tags: t-sql

I can I 52 previous weeks listed from todays date? Or if simpler get the first day of the previous 52 weeks?

Thanks
E

Comment: Have you done any research before asking???  Have you tried Google???

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is using the BETWEEN inside your WHERE clause in conjunction with using the DATEADD() function....
For example if you have a dbo.Date table with a DATETIME or DATE column...

```
SELECT DATEPART(week,Date) as Week
FROM dbo.Date
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(Week,-52,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```